How to determine the correlation between a discrete variable and a continuous variable?
I have 9 conditions (discrete variables) with each having only two states: occurrence (corresponding to 1) and non-occurrence (corresponding to 0), resulting in a total of approximately 511 combinations (excluding the cases where nothing occurs). Each combination corresponds to a result value (continuous variable) ranging from 0 to 100.
I want to know the contribution of each condition to the result value, i.e., which condition makes it easier for the result value to become larger, and which conditions have little impact on the result value.
Furthermore, if I have more conditions (up to a maximum of 34 conditions), how can I expand upon this approach?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Have a look at shapley values. They are the best approach to solve your problem.

Furthermore, this has nothing to do with correlation, since you do not seem to have any random variables. You should change the title of the question accordingly, e.g. change "correlation between" to "contribution to"

@gg Thank you for your answer. The Shapley value does indeed meet my requirements very well. However, when applying this method to more conditions, I encountered problems. Assuming I have 34 conditions, I cannot obtain the values corresponding to all 2^34 combinations. In the presence of data missingness, are there any corresponding modifications? I have not found any relevant information online.

I fear computational feasibility IS the big issue with Shapley. There are only limited workarounds. You may want to group variables or you can use probabilistic sampling according to certain combinatorial weights. Have a look at this blog for example.
